# Issue with Rendering Tab Titles Using flowbite-react Library

Tags: reactjs, tabs, flowbite

I am currently working on a project using the [`flowbite-react`](https://www.flowbite-react.com/) library to create tabs within a Reactjs application. While attempting to display tab titles dynamically using a `map` loop, I have encountered an issue where the titles are not showing.

**Problem Description:**

I have a Reactjs component where I conditionally render tabs based on the `contentType`. When `contentType` is set to "resources," I map over a `content` array and attempt to display tab titles and descriptions for each element in the array. However, I am experiencing difficulties with the titles not showing up.

**Code Snippet:**

```
{
  this.props.contentType === "resources" && (
    <Tabs.Group aria-label="Pills" style="pills">
      {this.props.content.map((el, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Tabs.Item className="Chinmoy" key={i} title={el.label}>
              <p className="">{el.description}</p>
            </Tabs.Item>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </Tabs.Group>
  );
}
```

**Expectation:**

I expect the titles to be displayed for each tab, with the `el.label` values from the `content` array being used as tab titles, while it works properly on the library documentation on a static jsx code, see [here](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/tabs#tabs-with-pills).

**Actual Result:**

However, the titles are not showing up as expected, and I cannot identify the root cause of this issue.

**What I've Tried:**

- I have confirmed that the `el.label` values in the `content` array are not empty or undefined.
- I've checked the library's documentation, but I couldn't find any specific guidance regarding this issue.

**Screenshot:**

[image]